# How to implement a recursive DFS in Clojure (without using a vector / stack)

Tags: python, clojure, depth-first-search

How would I code the equivalent of the following python in clojure, but strictly using recursion for the stack management (e.g. not using a loop/recur with a vector acting as the frontier)? 
 I realize it's fairly simple with a vector maintaining your paths and just peeking / popping, but I'm doing this as a thought exercise.

**Python Version**

---

```
def dfs(start,successors,goal,visited=set()): 
    if start not in visited:
        visited.add(start)
        for s in successors.get(start):
            if goal(s): 
                return s
            else:
                res = dfs(s,successors)
                if res: return res #bail early when found
    return False
```

**Clojure Version**

---

```
(defn dfs [start goal? successors visited]
  (if (goal? start) 
       start
      (when (not (contains? visited start))
             (mapcat #(dfs % goal?  successors (conj visited start)) 
                      (successors start)))))
```

Since iteration is controlled by a call to map in the Clojure version, you can't really bail early the way you can in Python e.g. `if goal(s): return s`. 
 Since you are collecting the recursive calls inside of a list with map, you are forced to evaluate every possible node even after the target is found.  Only then after all nodes have been explored do you get the result.

---

Now, I know I can do something like this (I know this isn't pretty... just trying to provide a quick example, feel free to suggest improvements!) but I'm primarily interested in seeing if there is a way to avoid explicitly using a stack, and letting the call stack do the work like in the python version.

```
(defn dfs-non-rec [frontier goal? successors visited]
  (loop [f frontier g? goal? s successors v visited]
        (let [node (peek f)]
             (cond ; case 1
                   (goal? node) 
                    node
                   ;case 2
                   (not (contains? v node))
                   (recur (vec (concat (pop f) (successors node))) g? s (conj v node))
                   ;case 3
                   :else 
                   (recur (pop f) g? s (conj v node))))))
```

How should I approach this?

**EDIT**

---

There was some confusion on my part as to whether some of the provided answers were in fact depth-first.  The confusion stemmed from an assumption I made about the input, which I should have provided in this post originally.  I had assumed the input as an adjacency list, which represents a *graph*, rather than a *tree*

```
(def graph  {"a"  ["b","c","d"],
             "b"  ["a","e","f"],
             "c"  ["x","y"],
             "d"  [],
             "e"  [],
             "f"  [],
             "x"  ["c"],
             "y"  ["e"]})
```

then when converted to a seq, the order followed is in-fact depth-first *for that resulting tree* created by calling seq on the graph, however the order implied by the adjacency list is not followed, because the graph structure is lost in the conversion.

So if you are looking for the node `x` starting at the `a`, I would expect the traversal order to be `adcyex`, rather than `abcdbaefcxy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all you don't really need to check tree for loops, since clojure's data structures don't have circular references (unless you don't use mutable state with `atom`s referencing to another atoms, which is an obvious code smell). The simple way of traversal could look like this (this way is referenced by lots of lisp (and overall programming) books):

```
user> (defn dfs [goal? data]
        (if (goal? data)
          data
          (loop [data data]
            (when-let [[x & xs] (seq data)]
              (cond (goal? x) x
                    (coll? x) (recur (concat x xs))
                    :else (recur xs))))))

user> (dfs #{10} [1 [3 5 [7 9] [10] 11 12]])
10

user> (dfs #{100} [1 [3 5 [7 9] [10] 11 12]])
nil
```

in addition there are more concise (and thus idiomatic i guess) ways to do this in clojure. The simplest one is to use [tree-seq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/tree-seq):

```
user> (defn dfs [goal? tree]
        (first (filter goal? (tree-seq coll? seq tree))))
#'user/dfs

user> (dfs #{10} [1 [3 5 [7 9] [10] 11 12]])
10

user> (dfs #{100} [1 [3 5 [7 9] [10] 11 12]])
nil

user> (dfs (every-pred number? even?) [1 [3 5 [7 9] [10] 11 12]])
10
```

`tree-seq` is lazy, so it only traverses tree until you find the needed value.

another way is to use clojure's [zippers](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.zip):

```
user> (require '[clojure.zip :as z])
nil

user> (defn dfs [goal? tree]
        (loop [curr (z/zipper coll? seq identity tree)]
          (cond (z/end? curr) nil
                (goal? (z/node curr)) (z/node curr)
                :else (recur (z/next curr)))))
#'user/dfs

user> (dfs #{10} [1 [3 5 [7 9] [10] 11 12]])
10

user> (dfs #{100} [1 [3 5 [7 9] [10] 11 12]])
nil

user> (dfs (every-pred number? even?) [1 [3 5 [7 9] [10] 11 12]])
10
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree about the checking for cycles part.  Even with immutable structures you can still have graph cycles.  if the graph is bi-directional e.g. `{:a [:a :b] :b [:b :a]}` then you would get stuck in an infinite loop without keeping track of visited nodes.

Comment: @Solaxun right, for graphs you describe it is so. But for simple trees where all the children are the elements of nested collections like in this case, it just doesn't make sense

Comment: I could have been more explicit in my description I suppose, but I never provided that input or said it was a tree :)  Also - isn't your first example really doing a BFS?  It looks like you process the children `xs` left to right. How would this work if you are dealing with a graph structure where you want to enter at a specific point, generate children, and proceed from there -  rather than processing the entire tree sequentially.

Comment: @Solaxun it is obviously a DFS, just look once more at the algorithm, and add traces (for example trace x after when-let). It would also be nice, if you could add some desired input to your question, then it would be easier to reason about the validity of the solution ))

Comment: Fair enough on the input - I originally didn't think there would be a difference in DFS regardless of the input, but I was wrong.  I think my confusion resulted form my assumption of an adjacency list as input (see updated question), which generates children as you go through the tree.  If you generate as you go, I don't think the provided answer guarantees DFS traversal order, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Solaxun looking at the algorithm, you can see that you always prepend 
 next depth level items to traversal candidates, and then walk them left to right, going down when another branch is met. So i would surely state it is dfs. Some experiments with paper and pencil could prove it

Comment: For a tree, yes, but for a graph, no. Look at the traversal order for the provided graph.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like the following, which uses [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) for testing:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))

(def data [[1 2 [3]]
           [[4 5] 6]
           [7]])

(def search-result (atom nil))
(defn search-impl
  [goal? data]
  (when (= ::not-found @search-result)
    (if (goal? data)
      (reset! search-result data)
      (when (coll? data)
        (doseq [it data]
          (search-impl goal? it))))))

(defn search [goal? data]
  (reset! search-result ::not-found)
  (search-impl goal? data)
  @search-result)

(dotest
  (println "1 => " (search #(= 5 %) data))
  (println "2 => " (search #(and (integer? %) (even? %)) data))
  (println "3 => " (search #(= [4 5] %) data))
  (println "4 => " (search #(= 99 %) data)) )
```

with results:

```bash
1 =>  5
2 =>  2
3 =>  [4 5]
4 =>  :tst.demo.core/not-found
```

Don't be afraid to use a bit of mutable state (in this case an atom) when it makes your program clearer and/or simpler.

If you really want to hide the atom from being globally visible, just do this:

```clj
(defn search2-impl
  [search2-result goal? data]
  (when (= ::not-found @search2-result)
    (if (goal? data)
      (reset! search2-result data)
      (when (coll? data)
        (doseq [it data]
          (search2-impl search2-result goal? it))))))

(defn search2 [goal? data]
  (let [search2-result (atom ::not-found)]
    (search2-impl search2-result goal? data)
    @search2-result))

(dotest
  (println "21 => " (search2 #(= 5 %) data))
  (println "22 => " (search2 #(and (integer? %) (even? %)) data))
  (println "23 => " (search2 #(= [4 5] %) data))
  (println "24 => " (search2 #(= 99 %) data)))
```

```bash
21 =>  5
22 =>  2
23 =>  [4 5]
24 =>  :tst.demo.core/not-found
```